# Camel exception ignore

Tags: exception, apache-camel

I want to ignore an exception (java.util.zip.ZipException) in route.  I want this exception not to be logged. I have tried onException clause and handled and continued with it. But it did not worked. especially handled and continued are not working together.

Comment: Show your route so we can see the code and can comment on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can put the code in doFinally block
```

http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you marking the exception as handled?

```
onException(ZipException.class)
    .handled(true)
    ...;
```

From http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html

```
// we mark the exchange as handled so the caller doesn't receive the
// OrderFailedException but whatever we want to return instead
```

Comment: Can you add your route to the question?